# How to pin cloth object to another object

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface, collision

[image]
[image]
I'm trying to pin a cloth object to another object.

[image]

I tried to fix it through the Vertex group. However, because the two objects are dissimilar objects,  cannot try to pin them together into the same vertex group.

Also, tried to fix the object using the sewing function, but the cloth object subdivision was done through the modifier, so it is difficult to cover the curve of the fixed target object.

**And, I'll fix the cloth to the object and add another frame bottom of the frame.**

[image]